# How to restore a backup on new switch. what are the steps?

Tags: ipv4, juniper

I am new in juniper networks.

Suppose I have a new switch with default configuration and I have a backup of the current switch.

What are the steps to restore the backup on the new switch and how to configure a management IP?

Comment: Please add the switch model in your question, the steps may vary by model.

Comment: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/juniper-ex-series-how-can-i-transfer-a-config-from-one-switch-to-anothe (where you first posted your question) seems to answer your question quite well.

Comment: copy and paste?  "The command "load replace terminal" can be used to copy a configuration from a text file to the J-series router." https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB10817&actp=search

Answer (score 1):

If you want to paste in the config in the hierarchical format, you can use "load override terminal"

The paste is relative to your current location in the hierarchy, so make sure you go to the top with "top"

Refer here for official info:  https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos16.1/topics/task/configuration/junos-software-configuration-file-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it on routers:

On the old one go into edit mode then run "show | display set" which will show you the set commands to put on the other device. Copy that.

On the new one I make sure is all clean config, go into edit mode and type "load set terminal" - which opens a sort of text file editor within the appliance - then I paste all the set commands from the old one and finish up with the escape character (^D).

Comment: The downside to using the set method is that you will lose annotations, and if your config is large, the input buffer will eventually max out, forcing you to cut and paste in sections.  Load merge terminal and curly-brace format is far superior IMO

Answer (score 0):

```
file copy your-server:/homes/fred/tmp/juniper.conf.gz-YOUR FILE
configure
load juniper.conf.gz-YOUR FILE
commit
```